# Toggling audio in an UWP app

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm building an app with optional audio support, and it will feature some kind of background sounds (like a looping soundtrack that keeps on playing in every page).

What I did is to create an audio manager that allows me to manage my sounds, and this should mute/unmute the audio based on user's settings.

Unfortunately this doesn't happen, and the audio keeps on playing even if the user disables it.

This is a sample of my code:

```
public static async Task StartSoundManager()
{            
    // Get audio stream from app folder
    // ...
    BackgroundSound.SetSource(currentStream, currentFile.ContentType);
    BackgroundSound.IsLooping = true;  
    ToggleSounds();
}

public static void ToggleSounds()
{                        
    BackgroundSound.IsMuted = !Settings.IsAudioOn;
}

public bool IsAudioOn
{
    // standard getter
    set
    {
        // save value
        SoundManager.ToggleSounds();
    }
}
```

After some tests, `IsMuted` is set correctly (I've also tried setting volume to 0) but nothing happens when changing settings.

Do you guys have any idea on why such a simple task is not working as expected? It seems to me that you can't change volume after setting the source, and this feels really wrong.

EDIT: more complete class

```
public static class AudioManager
{

    public const string BACKGROUND = "BACKGROUND.mp3";

    private static readonly MediaElement BackgroundSound = new MediaElement();

    public static async Task StartSoundManager()
    {
        // Get folder
        var folder =
                await (await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets")).GetFolderAsync("Audio");

        var currentFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(BACKGROUND);
        var currentStream = await currentFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        BackgroundSound.SetSource(currentStream, currentFile.ContentType);

        // Set mode and volume
        BackgroundSound.IsLooping = true;
        ToggleSounds();
    }

    public static void ToggleSounds()
    {   
        BackgroundSound.IsMuted = !Settings.IsAudioOn; // IsAudioOn is false, still the sound plays
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't Stop() / Play() make more sense?  At least you'll know whether the code actually runs :)

Comment: No, because that settings also toggles one-shot sounds. The idea is to write the sound logic as if it was always on and then use volume/mute to give user a choice. Also, I don't understand why the `IsMute` or `Volume` properties are not working, forcing me to overcomplicate this thing.

Comment: What's the `BackgroundSound` you are using? Is it a `MediaElement`? I can's reproduce your issue with `MediaElement`. `IsMuted` property work well in my side. Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT added more code. Sound starts playing as soon as I set the source, after that there's no way to mute it.

Answer (score 1):

[MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx) is a XAML control, to make [MediaElement.IsMuted property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.ismuted.aspx) work, we need to add `MediaElement` into Visual Tree. For example, in your code, we can change `BackgroundSound` to a public field like:

```
public static readonly MediaElement BackgroundSound = new MediaElement();
```

And then in a page (e.g. MainPage) add it to the page:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    await AudioManager.StartSoundManager();

    rootGrid.Children.Add(AudioManager.BackgroundSound);
}
```

After this, your `ToggleSounds` method should be able to work.

But since you want to keep on playing in every page, add `MediaElement` into the page may be not a good practice, here I'd suggest you use [**MediaPlayer** class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.aspx) instead of **MediaElement** like:

```
public static class AudioManager
{
    public const string BACKGROUND = "BACKGROUND.mp3";

    private static readonly MediaPlayer BackgroundSound = new MediaPlayer();

    public static void StartSoundManager()
    {
        BackgroundSound.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/{BACKGROUND}"));

        BackgroundSound.IsLoopingEnabled = true;

        ToggleSounds();

        BackgroundSound.Play();
    }

    public static void ToggleSounds()
    {
        BackgroundSound.IsMuted = !Settings.IsAudioOn; // IsAudioOn is false, still the sound plays
    }
}
```

For more info, please see [Play audio and video with MediaPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer).

Comment: I'm doing some tests with `MediaPlayer` but it doesn't even compile because it says that `MediaPlayer` doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @StepTNT What's the OS version you are using? [MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.mediaplayer) is introduced in Windows 10 Anniversary Update (version 10.0.14393.0), you need the latest Windows 10 SDK and set your project's Target version to "Windows 10 Anniversary Edition(10.0; Build 14393)".

Comment: I can't cut out people that didn't receive the update yet (including me). How can I make this work with both 10586 and AU?

Comment: @StepTNT For build 10586, we have to use `MediaElement`. You can use [ApiInformation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn949001) to detect whether you can use `MediaPlayer`. If not you can use `MediaElement` instead.

Comment: And this brings us to the original problem: how can I mute it without adding it the XAML tree?

Comment: @StepTNT I'm afraid there is no way without adding `MediaElement` into the XAML tree. Another choice may be using [Legacy Background Audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/legacy-background-media-playback).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation.  I have a ToggleMenuFlyoutItem for turning sounds on and off app-wide that writes to the local settings:

[image: toggle menu flyout]

Here is the XAML:

```
        <Button IsTabStop="False" Style="{StaticResource qButtonStyleFinal}" TabIndex="2" x:Name="btnMore" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}"
            Content="1" Grid.Column="37" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MaxWidth="60" MaxHeight="60">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/more_project.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem x:Name="mfiToggleSounds" Text="sound effects" IsChecked="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay, Path=Model.Sounds}"></ToggleMenuFlyoutItem>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="mfiExportExcel" Text="export to Excel" Tapped="mfiExportExcel_Tapped" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="mfiExportCSV" Text="export to CSV" Tapped="mfiExportCSV_Tapped" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="mfiEmailDeveloper" Text="email developer" Tapped="mfiEmailDeveloper_Tapped" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

Changes are handled in the property set event:

```
    private bool _sounds = true;

        public bool Sounds
    {
        get => _sounds;

        set
        {
            _sounds = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            localSettings.Values["sounds"] = _sounds;
        }
    }
```

Setting is loaded on the main page Page_Loaded event as follows:

```
            // retrieve settings
        var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("sounds"))
        {
            clsGlobal.statModel.Sounds = (bool)localSettings.Values["sounds"];
        }
```

And when I play a sound, a simple if condition is included:

```
if (clsGlobal.statModel.Sounds && clsGlobal.fileInputs.ContainsKey("problem.wav"))
                {
                    var snd1 = clsGlobal.fileInputs["problem.wav"];
                    if (snd1 != null)
                    {
                        snd1.Reset();
                        snd1.Start();
                    }
                }
```

I am using the AudioGraph API for my sounds.  Works better than the MediaPlayer route since that was giving me a weird situation where the sounds would not play sometimes on the first request.  AudioGraph works better for me and is really fast to play sounds.